# Find conditions in which $f$ is invertible over its entire image

Tags: real-analysis, inverse

Let us consider the following **bijective applications**:
$$f_{k}:A_{k}→B_{k}, k=1,2,\ldots,m$$
We construct the following application:
$$f=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m):A_1×A_2\times\cdots ×A_m→B_1×B_2\times\cdots \times B_m$$

Hence $f$ is a vector-valued function  from $A_{1}×A_{2}\times\cdots ×A_{m}$ to $B_{1}×B_{2}\times \cdots ×B_{m}$. If the determinant of the **Jacobian matrix** is nonzero everywhere, then by the **Inverse function theorem**, for every point $p$ in $A_{1}×A_{2}\times\cdots×A_{m}$, there exists a neighborhood about $p$ over which $f$ is invertible.
My **question** is: Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which $f$ is **invertible over its entire image**.

Comment: If $f_i$ is bijective and depends only on the $i$th component of the input, isn't $f$ always a bijection?

Comment: @user7530: Really, I do not know.

Comment: It seems to me that $f$ is necessarily bijective with $f^{-1}: B_1 \times B_2 \times ... \times B_M \to A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_M
\\(b_1, b_2, ..., b_m) \mapsto (f_1 ^{-1}(b_1), f_2 ^{-1}(b_2), ..., f_m ^{-1}(b_m))$

Comment: @Ar1 a bijection absolutely doesn't need to be continuous or even differentiable

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: I mean that $f$ is **invertible over its entire image**.

Comment: @AR1 ok then an injection absolutely doesn't need to be differentiable

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: I am searching for a global bijection.

Comment: @Ar1 I feel like I am repeating. Point 1: let $f: X\to Y$ be any function. Then $\tilde{f}:X\to f(X)$ is a surjection. So if $f$ is injective then $\tilde{f}:X\to f(X)$ is a bijection.